# libboost seems to be incomplete

Tags: ubuntu, boost, cpp-netlib

I'm trying to install [netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/) on my ubuntu 12.04. Since it needs libboost to be installed I installed libboost using:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

but here is the problem when I'm trying to install netlib according to [these instructions](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.10.1/getting_started.html) I get these errors:

```
In function `boost::thread::start_thread()':
undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
In function `boost::thread::join()':
undefined reference to `boost::thread::join_noexcept()'
```

Also I tried to compile netlib samples myself but I get this error:

```
fatal error: boost/network/protocol/http/server.hpp
```

I checked and in the folder boost is installed there is no network directory. I also downloaded boost package from its website but couldn't find network in those directories either. Should I do anything else in order to fix these errors?

Thank you

Comment: This does not solve your problem but the `boost/network/...` header files are included in the cpp-netlib source package. It's not an official boost library, maybe it is/was proposed and they decided to name it that way.

Comment: Didn't know that. It answers part of my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apt-get had installed libboost 1.48 and I figured there has been some problems with the old versions of boost:

[Ticket #7570](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7570)

[Undefined symbols for architecture i386 - "boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()"](https://github.com/mz2/boostoniphone/issues/5)

[It looks like your headers are outdated](https://github.com/mz2/boostoniphone/issues/6)

first using :

```
sudo apt-get remove libboost-all-dev
```

I removed boost then deleted all the files in `/usr/local/include/boost/` directory and then installed boost according to [this manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html).